# Flutter app crashes when using Matrix4.identity()..translate on button on mobile device

Tags: flutter

I made this button wrapped in a MouseRegion widget that has onHover effect with Matrix4.identity()..translate(0,-10,0), on web it works but when i run on mobile device it crashes and tells me :

```
═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following UnimplementedError was thrown building OnHover(dirty, state: \_OnHoverState#9e2af):
UnimplementedError 
The relevant error-causing widget was
OnHover
lib\\main.dart:7
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
\#0      Matrix4.translate
package:vector_math/…/vector_math_64/matrix4.dart:682
\#1      \_OnHoverState.build\
```

[image]

How can I make `Matrix4.identity()..translate(0,-10,0)` effect work on mobile?

This is the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OnHover extends StatefulWidget {

  final Widget Function(bool isHovered) builder;

  const OnHover({Key? key, required this.builder}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OnHoverState createState() => _OnHoverState();
}

class _OnHoverState extends State<OnHover> {

  bool isHovered = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final hovered = Matrix4.identity()..translate(0,-10,0);
    final transform = isHovered ? hovered : Matrix4.identity();

    return MouseRegion(
      onEnter: (_)=> onEntered(true),
      onExit: (_)=> onEntered(false),
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        transform: transform,
        child: widget.builder(isHovered),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onEntered(bool isHovered){
    setState(() {
      this.isHovered = isHovered;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the translate values to `double` instead of `int`:

```
final hovered = Matrix4.identity()..translate(0.0,-10.0,0.0);
```

This is the definition of the translate method from the [flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math/Matrix4/translate.html)

```
void translate(
dynamic x,
[double y = 0.0,
double z = 0.0]
)
```

I am not sure why `int` values work fine on the browser but there could be an internal conversion that is happening behind the scenes. Just use `double` values to ensure your app never crashes.